# AVFoundation: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh prevents recording from finishing

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm playing around with AVFoundation with inspiration from [this Technical Q&A code sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html) - screen capture via AVFoundation on Lion.

The sample code works well, but consistently fail if I change *AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium* to *AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh* with the **following error**:

> About to finish recording due to error Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11812 "Recording Stopped"
>   UserInfo=0x1001ccb60 {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions using the
>   recording device and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Recording
>   Stopped}

This happens when the session is stopped. The error code is an [AVErrorMediaDiscontinuity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ErrorConstants/Reference/reference.html). The recording is stopped gracefully with [mSession stopRunning].

I've read all documentation carefully, but cannot find any explanation to why this would happen from switching the session preset. To me, it appears as a bug. [mSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh] even returns true.
Simple source code:

```
@implementation ScreenRecorder

-(void)screenRecording:(NSURL *)destPath
{
    // Create a capture session
    mSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    if ([mSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh])
        NSLog(@"Can set high preset");
    else
        NSLog(@"CANNOT set high preset");

    [mSession setSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];// Fails, but AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium works splendidly


    input = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID: kCGDirectMainDisplay];
    if (!input) {
        mSession = nil;
        NSLog(@"Input not valid!");
        return;
    }
    if ([mSession canAddInput:input]){
        [mSession addInput:input];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Could not add input!!");


    mMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    if ([mSession canAddOutput:mMovieFileOutput])
        [mSession addOutput:mMovieFileOutput];
    else
        NSLog(@"Could not add movie file output!!");

    [mSession startRunning];

    // Delete any existing movie file first
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[destPath path]])
    {
        NSError *err;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[destPath path] error:&err])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error deleting existing movie %@",[err localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Starting recording..");
    [mMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:destPath recordingDelegate:self];
}

-(void)stopRecording
{
    NSLog(@"Stopping recording..");
    [mMovieFileOutput stopRecording];
}

//
// AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate methods
//
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
{
    NSLog(@"Started recording to %@", [fileURL description]);
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput willFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"About to finish recording due to error %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did finish recording to %@ due to error %@", [outputFileURL description], [error description]);

    [mSession stopRunning];
    mSession = nil;
}

@end
```

Logged output:

```
2013-05-28 19:51:45.058 ScreenEmailer[1330:303] Can set high preset 
2013-05-28 19:51:45.584 ScreenEmailer[1330:303] Starting recording.. 
2013-05-28 19:53:39.757 ScreenEmailer[1330:303] Stopping recording.. 
2013-05-28 19:53:44.758 ScreenEmailer[1330:303] About to finish recording due to error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11812 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo=0x1001ccb60 {AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions using the recording device and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped}
```

Why is this happening? And how is it possible to configure a higher recording quality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh requires you to define the recording area:

```
mSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[mSession setSessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
input = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc] initWithDisplayID: kCGDirectMainDisplay];
input.cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 700.0, 700.0); // is required for AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

Recording works splendidly hereafter.

Kudos to Gordon Apple <3